# Role base connection to RDS from lambda to insert data

Tags: java, postgresql, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have a java code given below which is capable of connecting RDS PostgreSQL instance.

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://endpoint/dbName","UserName", "Password");
System.out.println("Connected");
```

I can connect to RDS DB Instance using this code. But my question is that is there any way to connect the same RDS postgreSQL instance using AWS Login Role credential? Is it possible?

If it is possible please let me know how it will be?

If no please gimme the correct reason why it is not?

Please help me to get this.. I will be grateful to you if you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But my question is that is there any way to connect the same RDS
>   postgreSQL instance using AWS Login Role credential? Is it possible?

This is not currently possible. From IAM Roles and Users you can control who can provision a RDS instance, change other instance specific rules and snapshots. But it doesn't provide any access or control over the internals of a DB instance such as database creation, which DB User has access & etc specific to postgresSQL.

Comment: Thanks for your comment..Please answer one more question. Instead of end point can we use the vpc defined for the same postgreSQL db instance as a connection url? because vpc is public and i am asking to you this. I am sorry if there any mistake in my question. Please help me to get this too.. Thanks once more for answering me thank you soo much.I am really new to AWS

Comment: Hi @RamRam I didn't get your question quite. Is your need to put the RDS in a private subnet?

Comment: My endpoint is  : "postgre-db.cgycomwpwqbg.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432". Instead of this could i use VPC "vpc-7bd85a22"  ? that is my question.

Comment: No. You need to use the DNS url to access the DB. VPC id is just a reference for the virtual network boundary.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful replay

Comment: Hi @Ashan I have one more query to you that "Can't access RDS from external machine" - Publicly Accessible RDS in a VPC. What does it mean?   My RDS instance is publicly ccessible RDS in a VPC? Actually according to my requirement I created one lambda function to insert data to RDS postgreSQL from s3 bucket and add triger when a file fall on S3. I can complete it successfully. I am Sorry for asking this Please update me about this

Comment: When you say public for the RDS, it can be accessed outside the VPC (Which is not good for security). If you are accessing the DB through Lambda, place the Lambda function inside the same VPC.

Comment: @ Ashan. Thanks. I got my connection.RDS within VPC.